# Are there any downsides to enabling git rerere?

Tags: git, merge, git-rerere

I've read various things about git's `rerere` feature, and I'm considering enabling it.

> The `git rerere` functionality is a bit of a hidden feature. The name stands for **“reuse recorded resolution”** and, as the name implies, it allows you to ask Git to remember how you’ve resolved a hunk conflict so that the next time it sees the same conflict, Git can resolve it for you automatically.
>
> https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rerere

But I haven't seen anyone mention any possible problems that could arise while using `rerere`.

I have to assume there is a downside, or it would probably be enabled by default. So is there any downside to enabling rerere? What potential problems can it cause that would not otherwise occur?

Comment: When [automatic rerere is enabled](http://chuva-inc.com/blog/2012/09/fast-tip-enable-git-rerere-right-now) and it applies a previous resolution, does it display a message?  If so, what does it look like?  TIA!

Comment: @joeytwiddle, per [this article](https://hackernoon.com/fix-conflicts-only-once-with-git-rerere-7d116b2cec67), it would be of the form, `Resolved 'index.html' using previous resolution.`

Answer (score 87, accepted):

If you do a merge incorrectly, then discard it, then do the "same" merge again, it will be  incorrect again. You can forget a recorded resolution, though. From [the documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rerere.html):

> `git rerere forget <pathspec>`
>
> This resets the conflict resolutions which rerere has recorded for the current conflict in `<pathspec>`.

Be careful to use it on specific paths; you don't want to blow away all of your recorded resolutions everywhere. (`forget` with no arguments has been [deprecated](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=commit;h=5d2c3b01604a170c52262bf2751c55053d6bd8c1) to save you from doing this, unless you type `git rerere forget .` to explicitly request it.)

But if you don't think to do that, you could easily end up putting that incorrect merge into your history..

Comment: This is why `rerere` still leaves the files with conflicts marked as unmerged, so that you have to manually add them (hopefully after inspecting/testing them) before committing. You can always use `git checkout -m <path>` to check out the original conflicted version and redo the resolution if you have to.

Comment: That would make sense! Sounds like you need a new alias.

Comment: I think this is probably the main issue. Enabling rerere adds one more way for errors to sneak in unexpectedly. A merge that you abort (or rather undo by deleting it from the history) could still come back to haunt you later. Basically, it introduces a second history mechanism that is orthogonal to the actual history graph.

Comment: @RyanThompson Aborted merges don't affect rerere. (I often wish they did—I've sometimes aborted a merge because I set it up wrong, then needed to do the exact same resolutions when I set it up right.) As for deleting a merge from the history, why would you ever do that?

Answer (score 50):

As J. C. Hamano mentions in his article "[Fun with rerere](http://gitster.livejournal.com/41795.html)" (my bold)

> - Rerere remembers how you chose to resolve the conflicted regions;
> - Rerere also remembers how you touched up outside the conflicted regions to adjust to semantic changes;
> - **Rerere can reuse previous resolution even though you were merging two branches with different contents than the one you resolved earlier**.
>
> Even people who have been using rerere for a long time often fail to notice the last point.

So if you activate `rerere` on too broad a content, you might end up with surprising or confusing merge resolution because of the last point.

---

Another downside was `rerere` asking you for your pin for GPG signature (if you had activated `commit.gpgSign`).
This has been fixed with [Git 2.38 (Q3 2022)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73437414/6309)

Comment: The conflicting hunks do still have to match; it's fairly difficult for it to give a false positive.

Comment: And there is `git rerere gc` to forget old resolutions. With shorter time range the probability of mishit is less.

Comment: @gavenkoa True (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere#Documentation/git-rerere.txt-emgcem): by default, unresolved conflicts older than 15 days and resolved conflicts older than 60 days are pruned.

Answer (score 5):

I've got rerere globally enabled. I really haven't noticed any problems, and it usually seems to make my life easier.

Comment: Same here. No problems in 2+ years of usage.

Comment: @AndreyTarantsov any update after 12+ years of usage?

Comment: @manishma I’m not Andrey, but I still love rerere.

Answer (score 3):

I cherry picked a commit (in gitk) that only contained a binary file. Cherrypick failed due to conflict (which coming to think about it is natural) and I resolved the conflict keeping the cherry pick. I was surprised later to find in *another* rebased branch that my dlls did not behave - only to discover they were not carried into the rebase as (I speculate) automatic conflict resolution. So this is the only case I met (having rerere enabled) of running into counterintuitive (though I am sure perfectly consistent) behavior.

Comment: Cure: `git rerere forget path/to/compiled/bin.dll`

Comment: In the original case I got the conflict not on cherry picking but on rebasing but I don't think it makes a difference

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43280083/git-rerere-and-resolution-covering-non-conflicting-files), *Rerere* doesn't record parts of the resolution that are not in the conflicting file. One instance where this might occur is during the refactoring of a file, wherein certain lines are extracted and moved to another file, and a conflicting commit subsequently alters those lines. The resolution in this scenario would involve making the changes in the new file.

#### Example

##### Initial state

file `a`:

```
const foo = [
    'line 1',
    'line 2',
    'line 3',
];
// ...
const str = foo.join("\n");
```

##### Refactoring

new file `b`:

```
const foo = [
    'line 1',
    'line 2',
    'line 3',
];
```

refactored file `a`:

```
// ...
const str = b.foo.join("\n")
```

##### Conflicting Change

change to `a` in  another branch:

```
const foo = [
    'line 1',
    'line 2',
    'new line',
    'line 3',
];
// ...
const str = foo.join("\n");
```

##### Resolution

The resolution retains the refactored content in file `a` as is and adds the new line to file `b`. However, note that *Rerere* only reapplies the resolution to file `a` since it had conflicts during the initial resolution, whereas file `b` didn't encounter any conflicts initially.