# Git: Replay Series of Commits On top Of Other Commit

Tags: git

I had a series of commits like this:

`A-->B-->C-->D-->E-->F`

Commits `D` and later were a new feature, so I updated to make commits `D-->E-->F` a branch off of `C`:

`A-->B-->C
         \
          -->D-->E-->F`

Now I've made additional commits on top of `C`, so my repo currently looks like this:

`A-->B-->C-->C'-->C''
         \
          -->D-->E-->F`

I'd like to replay the commits in my feature branch (`D-->E-->F`) on top of `C''`, so the result is:

`A-->B-->C-->C'-->C''
                   \
                    -->D-->E-->F`

How might I do this?

I acknowledge there may be conflicts (which I'm happy to resolve), but figure there *has* be a better way than manually copying over changes.

Thanks!

Comment: Look into rebasing your new branch onto your initial branch: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Comment: the result commits should be `D'`, `E'`, `F'` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rebase ([`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)) will replay those commits:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase branchC
```

That will give you:

```
A-->B-->C-->C'-->C''
                  \
                   -->D'-->E'-->F'
```

Those commits will be different in that:

- their parent will have changed
- their content could have changed if you have to resolve some conflicts.

If you end up regularly doing that rebase, [don't forget to activate `rerere`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5519244/6309).

Comment: This is super helpful.  I did what you suggested, worked through the merge conflicts, and completed the rebase.  When I try to push my local `feature` branch to the remote branch, it tells me `error: failed to push some refs...hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.`  I'm a bit confused because, after the rebase, my local branch should be ahead of the remote one, I think?

Comment: @bclayman No: the rebase has changed the history of your feature branch: you need to force push it (`git push --force`). Which is OK if you are the only one working on that branch.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially rebasing the branched code to the parent.

Ref: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

First need to checkout the branch which needs to be rebased

```
git checkout branchD
```

Then need to rebase using "rebase" option of git command

```
git rebase parentBranch
```

**Note that with/without conflicts, new commits will happen and new SHA will be created for the commits.**

Comment: But... that is essentially what I *already* mentioned in my answer, isn't it?

Comment: Wanted to provide the doc link and the note that SHA will get updated after rebase. Just added the commands for more clarity.