# Confilict issue in merge

Tags: git, github, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I have following branch with respect to each environment for my Application.
Dev (Dev Env), UAT (UAT Env), Prod (Prod Env), Master Branch (This is in sync with Prod Branch and this acts as the Golden Image)

My current approach is whenever a new feature is required we create a new feature branch from Master, then merge into Dev, once Dev signed off we merge the feature branch with UAT and then to Prod.

**Problem:**

- Till now all of my three environment were in sync so this approach was working seamlessly
- Now recently we have changed our one of the existing feature lets call it ABC
- So we create a new bug-fix branch from Master, fixed the bug and then merged it with Dev.
- While merging we faced conflicts since we changed **abc to ABC**
- Now we have a new feature, so as per the practice we took the branch from Master, made changes and while merging with Dev we again faced conflict

This will be repeated till the bug-fix which is available on Dev is not released on Prod and the Master branch is updated.

How can I solve this issue?
So that each time merging Dev will not give me any conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

> while merging with Dev we again faced conflict

That is where [`git rerere`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere) can come in handy. I mentioned it in "[Are there any downsides to enabling `git rerere`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5519698/6309)" (to avoid having to resolve them on every rebase).

The idea is that your new feature branch, created from `master`, would benefit from `rerere` training when you merge it to `Dev`. It would resolve a known conflict in a predicable (and automated) manner.